# React className naming convention

Tags: reactjs, naming-conventions

As we know, we are supposed to use lowercase and dash for css class name in raw html (e.g. `<div class="lower-case-dash" />`). What about in React JSX?

For html elements and other React components, what is the naming convention for css class name? camelcase or dash?

```
<div className="divClass">Something</div>
<div className="DivClass">Something</div>
<div className="div-class">Something</div>
<SomeComponent className="SomeComponent" />
<SomeComponent className="some-component" />
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

TLDR: `PascalCase` and `Block__Element--Modifier`

Check out the official [doc](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-stylesheet) of `create-react-app`. It provides a minimum example of creating a custom component. The `js` and `css` filenames as well as the `className` are all following `PascalCase`.

```
// Button.css
.Button {
  padding: 20px;
}

// Button.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Button.css'; // Tell Webpack that Button.js uses these styles

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // You can use them as regular CSS styles
    return <div className="Button" />;
  }
}
```

Besides, the doc also provides an external [link](https://medium.com/seek-blog/block-element-modifying-your-javascript-components-d7f99fcab52b), which describes BEM naming conventions ([link](http://getbem.com/naming/)) for elements inside the component.

```
// MyComponent.js
require('./MyComponent.less');
import { Component } from 'react';
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MyComponent">
        <div className="MyComponent__Icon">Icon</div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// MyComponent.less
.MyComponent__Icon {
  background-image: url('icon.svg');
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-size: fit;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely true, In the docs, the CSS import example has the class names as Pascal case, But the modules have class names as camel case, So it is camelCase, and Airbnb a prevalent and well-established style guide also suggests module classes as camelCase

Answer (score 15):

Some of the naming conventions (Recommended) are:

1. **Component Name**

   Component name should be in `PascalCase`.

   **For example,** `MyComponent`, `MyChildComponent` etc.

---

2. **Attributes**

   Attribute name's should be `camelCase`.

   **For example,** `className`, `onClick` etc.

---

3. **Inline styles**

   Inline styles should be `camelCase`.

   **For example,** `<div style={{color: 'blue', backgroundColor: 'black', border: '1px solid', borderRadius:'4px'}}>My Text</div>` etc.

---

4. **Variable Names**

   Variable names can be `camelCase` (Good practice), `PascalCase` (Avoidable), `lowercase`, can also contain `number` and `special characters`.

   **For example,** `state = {variable:true, Variable:true, variableName:true}` etc.

---

5. **Class Name**

   Class names can be anything `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, `lowercase`, can also contain `number` and `special characters`, because after all it is a **string**.

   **For example,** `className="myClass MyClass My_Class my-class"` etc.

Comment: Can you share sources please?

Answer (score 4):

That totally depends on your (and your team's) preference. React (nor plain HTML) doesn't restrict you from using lower, dashed or camel-cased class names.

However, I would recommend that you choose an existing CSS convention like [BEM](http://getbem.com/naming/). This will make sure that class names stay consistent throughout the process (if followed correctly).

We've chosen for a custom convention in our projects to match our components class names with the component name.

Example:

```js
const NavBar = () => (
  <header className="NavBar NavBar--fixed">
    <div className="NavBar-brand"></div>
  </header>
);
```

As you can see, this looks a lot like BEM, except for the pascal-cased block, single dash separator for elements and a double dash separator for block modifiers.